# Chilkat - DownloadBd - SSL on port 80 is probably incorrect

Tags: chilkat

I use:
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/goLang_Http_Ref.html#method14

but I get this error:

```
ChilkatLog:
  DownloadBd:
    DllDate: Jun 25 2020
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.83
    UnlockPrefix: *********
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    VerboseLogging: 0
    url: https:\\*********.exe
    Component successfully unlocked using purchased unlock code.
    quickRequestDb:
      url: https:\\*********.exe
      a_quickReq:
        quickHttpRequest:
          httpVerb: GET
          url: https:\\*********.exe
          openHttpConnection:
            **SSL on port 80 is probably incorrect!  Normally HTTP on port 80 is non-SSL and port 443 is for SSL.
            Opening connection directly to HTTP server.**
            httpHostname: https
            httpPort: 80
            tls: True
            socket2Connect:
              connect2:
                connectImplicitSsl:
                  connectSocket:
                    connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
                      resolveHostname6:
                        getAddressInfo:
                          Failed to get host address info. (3)
                          **SocketError: WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND No such host is known.**
                          hostOrIpAddr: https
                          port: 80
                          Versions of Windows earlier than Windows XP are limited to handling IPv4 only
                          On Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP, IPv6 addresses are returned only if IPv6 is installed on the local computer.
                        --getAddressInfo
                      --resolveHostname6
                      Domain to IP address resolution failed.
                    --connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
                  --connectSocket
                --connectImplicitSsl
                ConnectFailReason: DNS lookup failed
              --connect2
            --socket2Connect
          --openHttpConnection
        --quickHttpRequest
      --a_quickReq
    --quickRequestDb
    Failed.
  --DownloadBd
--ChilkatLog
```

**My questions are:**

This is kinda strange that Chilkat is trying to use connection via http with port 80, especially when the URL string contains "https://"

Why this function is trying to use port 80 ?

How to force Chilkat to use SSL on port 443 ?

Remark:
I checked the URL which I provide with Google Chrome and this browser was able to download this particular file on exactly the same computer.

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at the URL within the Chilkat LastErrorText.  Your application passed "https:\\*****.exe".   Notice that you used backslashes instead of forward slashes after "https:".    The backslashes caused the URL parsing to return garbage results..